# Time sensitive task scheduling in Python in the context of IoV

Tags: python, time, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, sleep

I am trying to model a task scheduling/offloading problem in Python. I have a set of `T` tasks which should be processed by a network of Edge Servers.

The tasks have:

- a file size `FILE_SIZE`
- a number of instructions `LENGTH`

The edge servers have:

- a set of coordinates `x` and `y`
- an identification number `ID`
- a capacity `CP`
- a data transfer rate `DTR`
- a state `STATE` either idle or busy

The tasks are stored in a pandas DataFrame and the list of edge servers are stored in a dictionary.

Ideally, I would like for each task to be assigned a random edge server, and if it is unoccupied, set its state to `BUSY` for the amount of time it takes to complete the task. I have a function called `computation_time()` that computes it. If the edge server is busy, it would be assigned the closest edge server and so on. My goal in the end is to study the computation times, as well as the migration times of the tasks to unoccupied edge servers (with a function `migration_time()`.

My problem is that I can't wrap my head around how I can model this in Python, do I actually use time with the `sleep()` function? I want the tasks to be assigned and migrated in a parallel fashion, but don't know how to go about this in Python.

I tried looking up how to use the time package for the sleep function, and was thinking of doing some sort of object oriented sleeping (if that makes sense) but I don't know if that is possible, since I didn't find anything relevant on the internet.

I looked into the `multiprocessing` package, but I'm not sure it applies to my case here.

Comment: How "time sensitive"? python is not going to be a good bet for high frequency operations. You can certainly implement whatever sort of scheduling process you want to dispatch tasks to remote workers, but if you manage to get (round trip) responsiveness even in the 100ms range I'd consider myself lucky.

Comment: @Aaron Not very time sensitive I guess ? I only want to get the migration times and computation times. The thing is, I don't know how to model an edge server being busy or not, and that it should become free when s fictional seconds have passed.